# Why is my ImageView element mixed with my Button?

Tags: android, xml, button, imageview, opacity

I'm new to this so forgive me.  I've tried searching the documentation and the internet in general and I just can't figure it out.  This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It comes out looking like this:

[image: screenshot]

I just want the button to be completely opaque and not see the background image mixing with the button.  In other words, I want the image to be in the background and the button to appear solidly over top of it.  I played with the alpha settings of both elements and haven't been able to figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: Use an Opaque gray drawable for your button and set it as the background of your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the background color of the Button to whatever you want using `android:background`.  eg to make it red use `android:background = "#ff0000"`

Comment: You're welcome.  here is a handy link if you want to start getting fancy  with different burtton states. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Relative Layout (clicky)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html). It's powerful widget container but you need to be careful.

For the button you have specified `layout_centerInParent=true` and the layout manager does that - it sets your button in the center of the container (which is probably the whole screen)

In relative layout by default all child views are drawn at the top-left of the layout , that's why it paints ImageView there, you also have set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent` and it does that, fill the whole container.

If you want to position around (for instance below the ImageView) you need to say so: 
`android:layout_below="@id/ImageView_ID"` in the Button properties.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  The Button is where I want it in terms of being in the center of the view.  I just don't want to see the background image through the button.  My understanding is that the `android:layout_below` would move the button out of the center of the view to a Y coordinate below the image.

Comment: They try setting alpha: `android:alpha="1.0"` should make it completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the color of the button, then the provided answer does not suffice. Instead, put the button inside another layout with black background. E.g.:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```